# How to style the visible part of the element in css?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, styles

this is my result (i'm creating carousel):

[image]

For example i want to style the right image, Just the visible part not the whole part, How can i do that? If there is a JS way, What's that way?

Comment: You can take the class of the right image (assuming there is a unique class for it) and then apply styling to that class.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul i can style it, but style applies to whole part, i just to style the visible part (example that 30px part of right image that is visible)

Comment: Just asking, If the other part of the image is not visible, except the 30px part, will it even matter if the style applies to all the image?

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul yes it matters, I just want to style to that 30px (background gradient).

Comment: Why does it matter as opposed to @Debsmita. The css will be seen to the visible part only. If any special case exist then elobrate

Comment: You can use pseduo elements with 30px width and 100% height. Give it a absolute position, top 0, left 0 and style that. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul 30px is just for example, width is dynamic, (totaly i don't have width of the visible part)

Comment: Short answer, no you can't. You should rethink what you want and why you want it.